# How do you get the benefit of natural wonders that are mountains?

Tags: civilization-5

I started a game of Civilization 5 (BNW + G&K) and early on in the game I discovered a natural wonder called Cirro de Potosi, which is a mountain. When I discovered it, the advisor popped up and said that I gain happiness and get a benefit if the tile is worked (in this case +10 gold). I settled my second city right next to the wonder and I don't appear to be getting any benefit from this tile.

How do you get the benefit of natural wonders that are mountains? I can't assign citizens to the tiles and I am right next to the thing, which means it is within my borders, but looking at the city screen this new city still has 0 gold output, when I was expecting 10 gold per turn. I even advanced a few turns to see if it wasn't immediate but I still noticed no change.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To work a tile means you have a citizen on it, not a worker unit. To see which tiles are being worked, click on the city and enable manual citizen management. each tile within your borders will have a circle that is either gray (not being worked) or green (is being worked).

Comment: That's what I meant by worker. I swear that it would not allow me to put a citizen on the tile.

Comment: I know your starting city gets two citizens, does that not apply to additional cities? Maybe I thought there was two citizens because my starting city had two?

Comment: The city tile is always worked.  Your first citizen can work any other tile.

Comment: Ok then I swear I tried moving my first citizen to the mountain and it didn't let me.

Comment: @Dismissile Is it possible for you to upload the save file somewhere?

Comment: I didn't save the game. I tried a new one and found Mt. Kilimanjaro and it did work this time. I wonder if I just did something wrong to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what was said by VanBuzzKill, there are natural wonders that don't produce yield (food/production/gold/culture/faith/science) but give *happiness* - in case of these, you don't need to allocate citizen to work these tiles. Its enough to have the natural wonder within your civilization borders and you'll get the happiness boost.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is within the borders of your city, it should get a citizen pretty much automagically. If you have set manual specialists under the specialist buildings in the city details screen, this may affect this citizen placement.

Basically, if I want a natural wonder I try to put the city right up next to it, and it usually puts the next available citizen on it, kind of like a park ranger.